# Set programatically the width of a specific number of datagridview columns in vb net

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a number of columns that can be preset via a textbox. The first four columns have a determined width. I am trying to set the width of all remaining columns. This my code:

```
  dgv1.ColumnCount = CInt(Val(Form32.tbNbBox.Text) + 4)
  dgv1.Columns(0).Width = 100
  dgv1.Columns(1).Width = 70
  dgv1.Columns(2).Width = 70
  dgv1.Columns(3).Width = 50
  For i As Integer = 4 To CInt(Val(Form32.tbNbBox.Text))
     Dim c(i) As DataGridViewColumn
     For Each c(i) In dgv1.Columns
         c(i).Width = 40
     Next
```

As a result all columns have the same width (40). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand your 'nonsensical'. Assuming my tbNbBox = 32, If I delete the For Each loop, i find the 36 columns in place, the first four ones with correct widths (100, 70, 70, 50) and the 32 additional at property standard width 100. I wish to adjust their width at 40. On other hand if I  write:  dgv1.Columns(4).Width = 40, dgv1.Columns(5).Width = 40, etc upto column(35), I get the new widths, but cannot obtain a selected limit to the number of columns and don't know how to add programatically a preselected number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making it more complex than it should be.

```
  For i As Integer = 4 To CInt(Val(Form32.tbNbBox.Text)) -1
     dgv1.Columns(i).Width = 40
  Next
```

Comment: You are quite right, I was stupid. Here we have a saying: Why simplify things when they can be so complicated. Thank you so much.